# android - Replace removed view from viewgroup with a white space in OnDragListener

Tags: java, android

I am able to successfully drag and drop the view to container but I want to create a blank space after the view is dropped. In the below code, whenever the view is successfully drag and dropped. other views occupy the removed view.

Here is my code sample..

```
package com.skm.thegame;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        findViewById(R.id.color1).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.color2).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.color3).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.color4).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.color5).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.color6).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.color7).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.color8).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.color9).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.color10).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.color11).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.color12).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.color13).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.color14).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.color15).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());

        findViewById(R.id.box1).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.box2).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.box3).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.box4).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.box5).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.box6).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.box7).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.box8).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.box9).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.box10).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.box11).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.box12).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.box13).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.box14).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.box15).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

    }

    private final class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                        view);
                view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {
        Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
        Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    // do nothing
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
                    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                    ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                    owner.removeView(view);
                    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
                    container.addView(view);
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```